# Redux reducers: items.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state, destructuring

This is a question with a learning purpose, I am stuck in a specific approach. I am playing a little bit with Redux to learn it and I have a question about a part of my code. Let's say that I have the component that I am attaching as a screenshot which is pretty simple.

[image]

This item property is an object of 4 key value pairs (uuid, quantity, price, name ). I am trying to update the quantity in 2 ways. One is successful one is not.

In the reducer this works:

```
   if (action.type === QUANTITY_UPDATED) {
    return state.map((item) => {
      console.log(item);
      if (item.uuid === action.payload.uuid) {
        return { ...item, quantity: action.payload.quantity };
      }
    
      return item;
    });
   };
```

But this does not and return the error I mentioned that .map is not a function. It is probably a stupid mistake I am making but can't figure it out. Any input?

```
  if (action.type === QUANTITY_UPDATED) {
    const item = state.find((item) => item.uuid === action.payload.uuid);
    return { ...item, quantity: action.payload.quantity };
  }
```

Moreover, be sure that in Redux reducers, I can't mutate the properties. Could it be the reason?

Comment: If items.map is not a function in your component, what is items?

Comment: we can see (from the image - you should NOT post images of code though) that `items` is a prop passed to the component, but without seeing what you're passing as that prop, and how that's defined, we have no idea how to answer this question

Comment: It is an array of item objects.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, now I see the problem. You're always supposed to return the same type of state from your reducer.

Here, you are returning an array from your reducer:

```
   if (action.type === QUANTITY_UPDATED) {
    return state.map((item) => {
      console.log(item);
      if (item.uuid === action.payload.uuid) {
        return { ...item, quantity: action.payload.quantity };
      }
    
      return item;
    });
   };
```

But here, you are returning an object:

```
  if (action.type === QUANTITY_UPDATED) {
    const item = state.find((item) => item.uuid === action.payload.uuid);
    return { ...item, quantity: action.payload.quantity };
  }
```

An object is not an array.

The next time you try to update state, your reducer is going to be broken anyway because it expects the state to be in array.

If your state is an array, you need to always return an array from your reducer

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear enough. The props I pass is an array of items. Ah you are right, I just noticed.

Could you adjust the second implementation to put the item that is foun in the array?

I tried something like this but did not work:

return [...state, {...item, quantity: action.payload.quantity}

The key here is to update the quantity of a single item.

Comment: @botana_dev - I don't understand why you're trying to do anything else, you have an implementation that works. If you want to gain knowledge by learning stuff, make sure you have react dev tools and redux dev tools to your browser, and add lots of consoles